# can't upload images in question

Tags: bug, status-norepro

While asking a question on SharePoint StackExchange, I was trying to upload screenshot related to that question, but couldn't.
I clicked on Image button above text editor > dragged the image in upload popup and clicked on `Add Picture`. It kept on saying `Uploading...` but didn't proceed ahead.

The Image I am trying to upload is of `png` type and its size is `17KB`.

Comment: Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Yes. I tried in IE 11 and Chrome.

Comment: I've seen this before, and it may be that you're on an IP that is blocked from adding pictures (due to others posting SPAM images on the same IP-range). Can you try this from your home (if at work) or from work (if at home)?

Comment: ok I will try it from home.

Comment: It worked from home machine. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before, and it may be that you're on an IP that is blocked from adding pictures (due to others posting SPAM images on the same IP-range). Can you try this from your home (if at work) or from work (if at home)?